# Show overflowed content on hover when wrapper element is set to hidden with CSS + React + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a react app that has a sidebar. This sidebar vertically long and has `ul > li` elements. I wrap this element with React Scrollbar extension.

Problem is, Scrollbars sets `overflow` to `hidden`. My sidebar is responsive and when its on mobile view, if user hover any icon, it expands to show the text right to it. I also illustrated this on demo.

Due to scrollbar adds `overflow: hidden`, the text near to icon is not visible on hover. I am able to make it work if i set `overflow: visible` on scrollbar wrapper. However, this time, scrollbars stop working.

How can i keep scrollbars vertically and expand to the right when hover over icons and show the text.

Please see the **demo**: https://react-cgpzcq.stackblitz.io
**Editor** here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cgpzcq

I can also change props of scrollbar so any modification to the scrollbar element is also possible. Any idea?

[image: sample]

Comment: I don’t think you can without rendering the children outside the scroll container

Comment: Hm.. I also tried to set `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` on scrollbar to enable horizontally but disable vertically but it didn't worked out either. I think i will find another possible solution to show text for this item. Maybe tooltip. But if you have any suggestion, im open for it. Feel free to edit my code and post here.